# Excel combination of letters and numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel challenge and would appreciate any support! HELP!

I have two columns in Excel. The first one contains a sequence of letters and the second one contains 5 numbers (1,2,3,4 and 5). So it kind of looks like this:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
E  5
F  
G
H
```

...

I want to be able to combine every letter in the first column with each of the numbers and output this into a single column. In addition, I need a blank row in between the series. In other words, I need this:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5

B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
```

and so on.. I've been thinking about this for the better part of today but still can't think of anything..

Thanks in advance!!

Kind regards,
Antonio

Comment: Is it always A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H, and on...  and always 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: The first column goes from A to let's assume infinity (in reality, it's something like AAX) and the numbers are just 1,2,3,4 and 5. Thanks!!

Comment: Let's NOT assume it's infinity since a worksheet doesn't 5 × ∞ rows. Describing your situation in superlatives that have no meaning in fact is counterproductive to getting an intelligent focussed answer to your inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a solution that doesn't rely on the contents of Column A or B (Which is useful, but might not fit your needs), it just happily increments as you copy down the formula down the rows:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),6)=0, "", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, CEILING(ROW()/6, 1), 4), "1", "") &MOD(ROW(),6))
```

Put that in Row 1 of any column and copy down. Good times.

Comment: this is awesome, I might actually use this on its own since the end result is the same! brilliant this, thanks! :)

Comment: A [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) to achive the extents (+1) for the divisor would go a long way to make the function more universal.

Comment: That was @chancea's approach, which I upvoted because it was truer answer for the question asked. This approach ignores the data in column A and Column B completely. It assumes there is nothing to `COUNTA`, which is not exactly what was asked. I just made some assumptions about the question and assumed that OP was incrementing column names.

Comment: It also works to infinity ;)  Kidding... of course. The limitation being the number of columns that a version of Excel can hold.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is as follows:

```
   A   B
---------
1| A | 1
2| B | 2
3| C | 3
4| D | 4
5| E | 5
6| F |  
7| G |  
8| H |  
  ... ...
```

And the desired output is this:

```
    A   B   C
 -------------
 1| A | 1 | A1
 2| B | 2 | A2
 3| C | 3 | A3
 4| D | 4 | A4
 5| E | 5 | A5
 6| F |...|  
 7| G |   | B1
 8| H |   | B2
 9|...|   | B3
10|   |   | B4
11|   |   | B5
12|   |   |
13|   |   | C1
...         ...
```

You can use this formula starting in `C1` and auto-filling down:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("B"&MOD(ROW()-1,COUNT(B:B)+1)+1)<>"",INDIRECT("A"&INT(((ROW()-1)/(COUNT(B:B)+1))+1)),"")&INDIRECT("B"&MOD(ROW()-1,COUNT(B:B)+1)+1)
```

Note: This will have to be modified if the data does not start on row 1.  But this works with *any* combination of letters and numbers.

Also there is no end case check here. So anything that is past `H5` will result in just the numbers repeating.  If an end case check is needed that can be easily added.

Comment: Hold on I noticed a small bug, in-process of fixing

Comment: Fixed, needed to add 1 to `COUNT(B:B)` -> `(COUNT(B:B)+1)`

Comment: Yep after B4 it goes to C5 :)